# Commercial IDE+Emulator for Android?

Tags: android

I'm an Android total-noob but in the last few weeks I've installed the JDK/Eclipse/Android SDK on 2 PC's.   Both installs took a day of tweaking and dealing with configuration problems and getting the different parts to play together, and generally were a PITA!   On one PC I'm STILL dealing with random, sporadic instances of the *"**HelloAndroid] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch'!**"*  problem that has been discussed here and on the Android Google group!   No one seems to know for sure what causes it.

ALSO in the last few weeks I've installed Visual Studio 2010 on the same PC's to do my regular work as a Windows sw developer.   On both PC's all I had to do was pop in the DVD, type in the product code, come back a few hours later and start coding!!

So my question is whether there is a commercial (i.e., $$) sw development environment for Android that installs and runs as easily as VS 2010 so I can focus my time on actual sw development and not on fighting with the development system.    Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[Jetbrains](http://www.jetbrains.com) has support for Android development in their IntellijIDEA IDE. You can check out their [page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_android.html) about their Android support.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options available depending on what exactly you wish to do.

A few pointers are here ..  [How can I use MS Visual Studio for Android Development?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1371939/808940)

You would be well advised to check [MonoDroid](http://android.xamarin.com/) which will allow you to C#.NET to run your android program.  It's vastly popular so probably worth a look.

Beyond this there are various other options however please read through some of the [answers provided in this list of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+visual+studio)

In some ways I would argue that bonding with eclipse is has it's learning curve but once overcome, I prefer it to VS (which I've used commercially for 10years).

If you decide to stick with it ensure that you have the Indigo release of Eclipse and the Latest ADT plugin for development.