# Android application Development in Visual Studio with C#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use MS Visual Studio for Android Development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371939/how-can-i-use-ms-visual-studio-for-android-development)

Is is Possible to start development of Android application in Visual Studio with C#.

If yes,
Can any one suggest the good links through which I can start development.

If No,
what should be alternate solution.

Comment: This has something related to you. <br/> Visit http://www.brutaldev.com/post/2011/01/15/Android-applications-in-C-using-Visual-Studio.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android sdk with eclipse might be a better combo I guess. C# and Visual Studio are better suited for Windows phone.

Comment: I have answered the question. The answer according to me is no, and the alternate solution is eclipse. I even said taht the proposed solution would fit better another type of development.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this: http://www.brutaldev.com/post/2011/01/15/Android-applications-in-C-using-Visual-Studio.aspx help?

Android development tends to be in Java (which is not entirely unlike C#) using the Android SDK and many people use Eclipse as their IDE with the ADT plugin. I can't see any reason not to use C# from what that link says, but I would imagine that a straight, native Java version would be preferable?

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html