# layout could not be loaded : android version not supported by the designer

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android

**Edit:this is about Mono for android**

I am trying to develop android application using vs2010

but problem is that when i am enter in layout folder main.axml file that time the message show on that window show

**layout could not be loaded : android version not supported by the designer**

please help and wht i do now for that issue

Comment: what's the benefit of using vs to develop an Android App for you? you can find more information on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371939/how-can-i-use-ms-visual-studio-for-android-development

Comment: i can keep my c# coding by using mono for android and i have to save time now,so i need it,can you help about this issue?

Comment: sorry as you can see(no answer) most of the people here develope with eclipse and your problem is not the usual one , so you should try change some of your vs library or settings to solve the issue.maybe you have to change your compiler compliance level or update your designer for approporiate SDK version

Comment: Does this also happen if you create a new layout?

Comment: i get this message in all case,but same code,show designer in other systems,this happen in MonoDevelop application too,i still get it,Xarmin support could not help me about this,even i reinstall mono and all dependecies

Comment: solved,see last answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by reinstall everything,i had done this before,but now i reinstall the jdk.

before i was installed jdk 7,but now i install jdk 6 and problem solved

i don't know why it happened.