# Is it possible to code Android Programming in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, android, .net, windows, visual-studio-2012

I have a sound knowledge of Visual C#.NET. And I want to program Android Apps. But as I am too much familiar with visual studio environment, therefore I want to know the way to program Android in Visual C#.NET language.

There is a related question in given link on stackoverflow [Related Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954756/android-in-visual-studio)

But i found nothing useful from that.

Comment: Did you follow the other link in there?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371939/how-can-i-use-ms-visual-studio-for-android-development

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have to look on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the cleanest solution is probably Xamarin:
http://xamarin.com/

But that costs money.

You can develop in visual studio in Java using the following:
https://code.google.com/p/vs-android/

You can develop in C# for free for Android using Mono, although it is not in Visual Studio:
http://monodevelop.com/Download/Mono_For_Android

IMHO, Java is very similar to C# so you might be better off learning the intended way to program Android applications than trying to fight it.

Comment: +1 for the last point alone, there aren't a whole lot of different features in Java that would trip up someone from a C# background; only really there is no `string` alias, only `String`