# I have downloaded visual studio community 2013. But I do not find option for android and ios apps.

Tags: visual-studio

I have downloaded visual studio community 2013. But I do not find option for android and ios apps.  Please can anyone help me with that. I have visited https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx this link too but am unable to know how to start with android and ios.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use MS Visual Studio for Android Development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371939/how-can-i-use-ms-visual-studio-for-android-development)

Comment: Did you use "modify installation" in the installation executable? You should be able to select Android and iOS support there (which is turned off by default). This might just be aimed for VS2015 though.

Answer (score 0):

For developing ios and android application in VS 2013 you should use Cordova.
You can find it under Other languages-> JavaScript->Apache Cordova Apps
[image]