# Port android app from Android Studio to Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: java, android

I have an app written in Android Studio, that I want to work on using Visual Studio.

Is there a way to import my project into Visual Studio?

Comment: Why would you rather use Visual Studio?

Comment: While your question is about importing an already existing project, there is a question regarding Android development in VS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371939/how-can-i-use-ms-visual-studio-for-android-development

Comment: I want to use VS because it can do cross platform development, which would be a definite bonus.  The first app I want to release is almost done in Java, and if I want to release it on an iDevice, most of my work should be done...

Comment: You almost certainly have a fundamental misunderstanding about how this all works.

Comment: Using Cross-platform is a nightmare in the long run, you cant even utilize the full potential of each device and you are only limited to some API's.

Comment: Any advance on this? VS2015 and VS2017 support importing Eclipse projects, but not Android Studio so far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to convert it. Android Studio only supports IntelliJ and not Visual Studio, but you could rewrite the project in xamarin which is supported by visual studio.

Comment: can you provide more details?

Comment: Android Studio only supports IntelliJ and not Visual Studio, but you could rewrite the project in xamarin which is supported by visual studio.

Comment: But it was the answer of the question

Answer (score 0):

Try VisualStudio Community, it's designed for cross-platform development. Use your "gradlew" files for project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can try transcoding it. However, to publish apps on different platforms, you need to sign up for app development accounts on those platforms and use the respective tools to publish apps. For example, if you want to publish your app on the Microsoft Store, you need to sign up for an app development account on Microsoft and use Visual Studio to publish the app.