# Develop an android app with Visual Studio 2010 and C#?

Tags: c#, android, html, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I've seen several versions of this questions, but none of them seem to give me the answer I'm looking for.

I'm a software engineer and I do all my development with VS2010, C#, and Sql Server as back-end. An opportunity came up where the client wants to develop a simple application to run in a tablet. We initially agreed on an android tablet (the 7" Amazon Fire) since I still haven't found a $50 Windows tablet, and this software will be deployed in many units.

It's an uphill battle since this is the first time I'd create an app designed for an android tablet, and I'd like to try working on the project only if I can use the tools that I currently use.

So my question is: can one use VS2010/C# to develop an android app? Or would I need to learn a new language, download 3rd-party software, etc?

I can download VS2012 or a newer version of the IDE, but my only requirement is that I can use what I already know, or possibly, if I can purchase a time-tested plug-in to Visual Studio.

I'm also open to HTML5, only if I can develop in VS2010. The app can run in a browser.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use Xamarin to develop Android apps in C# - I'm not sure whether the plugin supports such an old version of VS though. See https://xamarin.com/

Comment: Please check out this topic:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371939/how-can-i-use-ms-visual-studio-for-android-development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371939/how-can-i-use-ms-visual-studio-for-android-development). But I recommend using Xamarin (C#) or just Android Studio (Java).

Comment: @Yvo. I read the link. But if you look at the accepted answer, I will need to go through several additional downloads and installations, and I know for a fact that one of them will fail (always happens). And I honestly don't want to go through the trial-and-error process of using open-source software.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Community edition supports Xamarin and can install all the required components including an android emulator. With Android you're not going to be able to avoid open source. The operating system and all its tools are. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/xamarin-vs.aspx You'll need a xamarin licence in addition to Visual Studio itself.

Comment: @jessehouwing, thanks for the suggestion. By avoiding open source, I meant not wanting to install separate 3rd-party downloads manually, but have a trusted app do all that for me.

Comment: I know for a fact that after I download/install Cygwin, then the JDK, then vs-android, then Apache Ant, etc, and then set the environment variables, something's not gonna come out right when I open VS and/or build the app. It's never that easy.